# Javascript convert text to hyperlink that contain html tags

Tags: javascript

I created a simple JavaScript function that can take a string and replace it with a hyperlink.  My question is how to convert a string that contains html tags.  I have not been able to figure that part out.  Any help is appreciated.

```js
function createlink( text) {




var replacetxt = "<a id=\"'Temp5'\" onClick=\" testfunction()\" href=\"#\" style=\"color: black;background-color: green;text-decoration: none\">" +  text + "</a>";
var re = new RegExp(text,'g');

document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(re, replacetxt);



}


//This Works
//createlink("My first paragraph");

//This does not work
createlink("My first paragraph~2");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph<sup>~2</sup></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try with `My first paragraph<sup>~2</sup>` value instead. [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) is containing the **HTML** portion as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the  tags to your input - as you're performing an HTML string match.

```js
function createlink( text) {

var replacetxt = "<a id=\"'Temp5'\" onClick=\" testfunction()\" href=\"#\" style=\"color: black;background-color: green;text-decoration: none\">" +  text + "</a>";
var re = new RegExp(text,'g');

document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(re, replacetxt);
}
function testfunction(){
  alert('testfunction called')
}


//This Works
//createlink("My first paragraph");

//This does not work
createlink("My first paragraph<sup>~2</sup>");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph<sup>~2</sup></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read on this link - https://medium.com/better-programming/whats-best-innertext-vs-innerhtml-vs-textcontent-903ebc43a3fc

```js
function createlink(text) {
  var replacetxt = "<a id=\"'Temp5'\" onClick=\" testfunction()\" href=\"#\" style=\"color: black;background-color: green;text-decoration: none\">" + text + "</a>";
  var re = new RegExp(text, 'g');
  var el = document.getElementById('t');
  
  el.innerHTML = el.innerText.replace(re, replacetxt);
}

function testfunction(){
  alert('Random test function is called for testing')
}

//This Works
//createlink("My first paragraph");

//This does not work
createlink("My first paragraph~2");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h1>My First Heading</h1>
  <p id='t'>My first paragraph<sup>~2</sup></p>

</body>

</html>
```